# Loop CPT by ID through Wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to loop only custom post types using the WP loop, but only shows the ones I give by ID.

This is my "normal" loop right now:

```
<?php $args = array(

    'post_type' => 'referenties', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'order' => 'DESC',

  ); ?>


<?php 
    $number = 0; 
    query_posts($args); 
    if(have_posts()):  
    ?>




<!-- /Carousel script -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="carousel-loop">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $number++; ?>"></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </ol>
    <div class="controle-buttons">
      <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i></a>
      <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
          <!-- Carousel nav -->

    <div class="item">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(150,150)); // Declare pixel size you need inside the array ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                        <?php $bedrijf = get_field('naam_bedrijf'); ?>
                        <?php $feest = get_field('feest'); ?>
                        <?php $link = get_field('mylink'); ?>
                        <?php echo '<p>Bedrijfsnaam: ' . $bedrijf . '</p>'; ?>
                        <?php $post_object = get_field('mylink');
                            if( $post_object ): $post = $post_object; setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                                <p>Feest type: <a style="color:#ff6600" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
        <h4>Opmerking</h4>
            <p><?php echo custom_field_excerpt_longer(); ?></p>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
                <?php echo '<p>' . wp_review_show_total() . '</p>'; ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

But I only want to show post ID's: 2706, 2462, 2514, 2511 and 2505.

The loop is shown in a carousel, this works fine. But I just want the ID's to show and not all posts added.

Comment: [Don't use `query_posts` for custom queries!](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) Use either [WP_Query()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), or [get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) for fetching posts.

Comment: If you could tell me how to correctly make the loop, or point me in the correct way, I would like to make. I'll be happy to use  WP_Query()...

Comment: I've added the answer. I'd recommend reading the codex about `WP_Query`. It has many different query types covered, and explains everything pretty good :)

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this:

```
<?php 

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'referenties',
        'post__in'  => array(2706, 2462, 2514, 2511, 2505),
        'order'     => 'DESC',
    ); 

    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();

            //post content output goes here

        }
        // Restore original Post Data
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }
```

The `post__in ()` argument uses array with desired post ids to retrieve.

Don't use `query_posts` for custom queries. Too much that can go wrong.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi dingo_d, thanks for your code. Just to be sure.

Ill have to post my cols and stuff where you put //post content output goes here... 

Right, just start adding my code. Because when I do that the page doesn't work anymore...

Comment: You do not want reset postdata if you do not have posts because you haven't changed the `$post` global. I have made the necessary change in your post ;-)

Comment: Oh, right, I pasted from the `WP_Query` page, thanks Pieter :)
@Steggie place the loop inside your wrappers, and the part you want to repeat, you place inside the if condition, so that as long as the condition from the query is true you'll get posts. Pretty standard wp loop, should be working fine.

Comment: @dingo_d My pleasure. The codex is not always correct, and in some cases just a load of crap with wrong info. The issue is, the codex is not maintained by WordPress developers, but normal users like me and you. Anyone with a valid wordpress.org account can alter the codex as they see fit, so this do lead to incorrect info being added. This is sad because people who do not really know WordPress never know what is correct and what is not, and they believe the codex because the codex is WordPress

Comment: I've seen that they have been moving stuff from codex to developers. Not sure I like the new look, but if it's maintained by a bit experienced users that could help people a lot :)